# Use Managed Identity of Azure Function when calling another Azure Function

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

There's a helpful [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad?toc=/azure/azure-functions/toc.json#daemon-client-application-service-to-service-calls) that describes how to configure security for a daemon client application. This works ok but it means the client app must present a client id and client secret to the /token endpoint of AAD in order to obtain the OAuth2 access token.

This makes no use of managed identity and means I need to ensure the security of the client secret of the daemon app. If the client id and secret of this app were to fall into the wrong hands, there's nothing to prevent a bad actor obtaining an access token and calling the target service.

I realise that a certificate can be used instead of a client secret but my question is, can this be avoided through the use of the managed identity of the client daemon app?

Comment: I've written on article on doing this ;) https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions. There is still no way to add app permissions to managed identities through the Portal so you'll need to use PowerShell/Graph API to do that.

Comment: Thanks again @juunas. Seems strange that Microsoft still don't support this via the Portal. I guess the "standard" way is to create an app registration for the client and add an app role. This still means custom code is required in the target service app (to check for the presence of the role in the access token), so I think the solution you documented is better